# Testcafe - beforeAll and afterAll tests in a file or all files

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

If I have 3 test files, and each file has several fixtures and tests, like this

```
file1.js
    fixture1
        test1
        test2
    fixture2
        test3
        test4
file2.js
    fiture3
        test5
        test6
    fixture4
        test7
        test8
file3.js
    fixture5
        test9
        test10
        test11
    fixture6
        test12
        test13
```

I found that I could use `fixture.after()` and `fixture.before()` for a certain fixture. I could use `test.after()` and `test.before()` for a certain test.

If I want to set the environment for file2.js and clean it when all tests in file2.js (test5, test6, test7, test8) are executed, does `testcafe` have such functions?

If I want to set the environment for all files and clean it when all tests are executed, does `testcafe` have such functions?

Thanks

---

### Update 1

After reading [Hooks before and after test runs](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403435/guides/intermediate-guides/hooks#hooks-before-and-after-test-runs) provided by vasily.strelyaev, I created `.testcaferc_seq.js` and added `"test": "./node_modules/.bin/testcafe chrome --sf ./integration_tests/file2.js --live --config-file .testcaferc_seq.js"` in package.json.

The `.testcaferc_seq.js` is

```
const utils = require ("integration_tests/utils/afterAllTestRunner.js");

module.exports = {
  hostname: "localhost",
  ...

  // before all and after all tests
  hooks: {
    testRun: {
      before: async ctx => {
        console.log("---------------- \n before all tests \n ---------------------");
        utils.cleanUsers();
      },
      after: async ctx => {
        console.log("---------------- \n after all tests \n ---------------------");
        utils.cleanUsers();
      },
    },
  },
}
```

However, the hook did not work, and I could not see the two sentences from the two `console.log(...)`. Did I miss something?

One more question, if I want to control the browser (such as chrome) to do some pre/post testRun steps, how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no built-in way to run a hook before the first fixture in a specific file starts, and after the last fixture in that file ends. As a workaround, you can put together all tests in this file in a single fixture and specify [its hooks](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403435/guides/intermediate-guides/hooks#hooks-for-individual-fixtures). Alternatively, if it is possible to run hook code multiple times in your scenario, you can create helper functions with setup and teardown code and call these functions from [each fixture's individual hooks](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403435/guides/intermediate-guides/hooks#hooks-for-individual-fixtures).

As for your second question, yes, you can use global test run hooks to set up an environment before the first test starts and clean it after all tests are finished: https://testcafe.io/documentation/403435/guides/intermediate-guides/hooks#hooks-before-and-after-test-runs.

You can find more information in our Hooks guide: https://testcafe.io/documentation/403435/guides/intermediate-guides/hooks.

Comment: Hi vasily.strelyaev, I added some problems and steps in the post. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are some problems with reading the config file. Look at the console, you will see:

```
An error has occurred while reading the "....testcaferc.js" configuration file.
```

That is why global hooks don't work. This error may be caused by the `integration_tests/utils/afterAllTestRunner.js` module. Try to run it without using it.

Regarding browser manipulation in the before/after testRun hooks. This is not supported.